# Cross-browser cookie inconsistency?

Tags: java, jsp, gwt, cookies

We have come across quite an interesting problem in the past few days, and I have been chasing my tail trying to solve it. I would appreciate some insight.

**The scenario:**

We have a GWT web application, and at some stage during the normal usage of the system, a user might need to enter his password to gain access to a certain part of the application. We do this by displaying a dialog that contains an iframe with a jsp, where the user then enters his password. This is encoded and sent to the jsp servlet, which validates the credentials and if successful, sends a cookie to the application informing it of a successful authentication.

**The problem:**

When we run the application in our local development environments, everything works perfectly. The requests get generated properly, and cookies get sent perfectly. However, when we run this in our client test environment (which is identical to our local env.), it works perfectly for Firefox, but not for Chrome and IE. (We literally take the exact war and drop it in both places).

Some packet sniffing seems to show that the cookie that gets generated on the server side by the jsp servlet

```
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

never reaches Chrome or IE, but it does for Firefox.

The traces we have on the server side indicates that the correct request does reach the servlet, and that all the same code runs every time for all browsers.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue? Our technology applicable stack is:

1. Java 1.6
2. GWT 2.2.0
3. Apache Tomcat 7.0.8

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out what was wrong.

It seems that the server time set on the test environment was 9 minutes behind the actual time. The cookie was set to expire after 1 minute, which would cause it to expire as soon as it reached the client browser. After changing the cookie to expire when the browser exits, everything works perfectly.

Comment: @Riley - Lol, thanks. Although I hate spending so much time trying to track down an issue and it ends up being something so silly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is to do with P3P settings -- IE in particular is very sensitive about P3P headers and the p3p.xml file.
If you google "cookies p3p" you will find lots of resources about setting this (it's just a http header and an xml file that needs to be made accessible).
And before you ask, the reason it works in your local environment is because IE will apply different privacy and security settings to the "Internet zone".